# Single tap doesn't work in combination with double tap

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

To image, I have attached several gestures and all but single tap worked as expected.

Below is the image along with gestures attached to it:

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "shatan_tree.png")!)
                .gesture(TapGesture(count: 2)
                            .onEnded({
                                // this code is executed as expected
                            }).simultaneously(with: DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global).onChanged({ 
                               // this code is executed as expected
                            })
                            .onEnded({ (value) in
                                // this code is executed as expected
                            })))
                .gesture(TapGesture(count: 1)
                            .onEnded({
                                // this doesn't work
                                print("single tap")
                            }))
                .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                            .onChanged({ (scale) in
                                // this code is executed as expected
                            })
                            .onEnded({ (scaleFinal) in
                                // this code is executed as expected
                            }))
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong and how to enable single tap gesture along wit other gestures?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is consumed by `DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0...`, so the solution either to make drag *really* drag at least by some

`DragGesture(minimumDistance: 1...`

or make single tap simultaneous

`.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture(count: 1)`

Comment: Thank you! I made a single tap simultaneous and it works.

Answer (score 0):

try

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let singleTapGesture = TapGesture(count: 1)
            .onEnded { _ in
                print("Single tap recognized.")
            }

        let doubleTapGesture = TapGesture(count: 2)
            .onEnded { _ in
                print("Double tap recognized.")
            }

        let combinedGesture = doubleTapGesture.exclusively(before: singleTapGesture)

        return Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .gesture(combinedGesture)
    }
}
```